# Java Collections-the number of words without repetition

Tags: java, string, collections, equals, compareto

I wan to create a method for which we give text(String) as an input argument.
The method will return the number of words without repetition.
For example: "cat, dog, Cat, Bird, monkey"
return value:4

How can I compare each Collections item with each other?
What I already have:

```
public class WordsCounter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    uniqueWordsCounter("cat, dog, Cat, Bird, monkey");
}

public static void uniqueWordsCounter(String text) {

    String processedText = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll(",", "");
    String[] words = processedText.split("\\s");
    List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(words);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) operation from the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```java
import java.util.*;

public class WordsCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        uniqueWordsCounter("cat, dog, Cat, Bird, monkey");
    }

    public static void uniqueWordsCounter(String text) {
        String[] words = text.toLowerCase().split(",\\s*");
        List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(words);
        System.out.println(wordsList);
        System.out.println("Count of distinct elements: "
                           + wordsList.stream().distinct().count());
    }
}
```

Example run:

```sh
$ java Demo.java
[cat, dog, cat, bird, monkey]
Count of distinct elements: 4
```

Note splitting on comma followed by optional whitespace instead of your replacing commas and then splitting, to help simplify things.

Comment: You can also use `Arrays.stream(words).distinct().count()`; no need for the List unless you need it for something else too.

Comment: Or even `Pattern.compile(",\\s*").splitAsStream(text).map(String::toLowerCase) .distinct().count()` as even the array is not needed and calling `toLowerCase` on the words is potentially more efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to keep track of all the unique elements present in your string after you separate it using the delimiter **","**
In your example, you are keeping cat and Cat as same ( ignoring case ) . Thus, you can use this logic.

```
public class WordsCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = uniqueWordsCounter("cat,dog,Cat,Bird,monkey");
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static int uniqueWordsCounter(String text) {

        String str[] = text.split(",");
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>() ; 
        for( String temp : str)
        {
            if ( !set.contains(temp.toLowerCase()))
            {
                set.add(temp);
            }
        }
        return set.size(); 
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
4
```

Comment: instead of checking if word is present in Set, directly add the word to Set(after converting it lowercase or uppercase) and return the size of the set(because Set will always keep only entry in its memory), this way we can reduce some TC of contains method.

Comment: tc of contains is O(1) only , so essentially it becomes tc of 0(1)*tc of add -> tc of add only

Comment: There’s a logically error in checking `set.contains(temp.toLowerCase())`, followed by `set.add(temp);` *without* `toLowerCase()`. It happens to work with the example data because the lowercase string comes first, but will fail with `"Cat,cat"`. This demonstrates why you should avoid redundant operations, not because of performance, but potential errors when the two operations are not in synch. Even if you need to perform an action for absent values, there is no need for a pre-test, as `add` returns whether the set was modified, `if(set.add(temp.toLowerCase())) { … }` would work.

Comment: @Holger yes, i understand, one way to rectify that is i store lower case values in the set. but as you have mentioned, i feel that is better approach